# Display external site video

Tags: html, video

I want to display other website videos (eg: DailyMotion, Youtube and Vimeo). How can I do this in my HTML code?

I want to use something like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

Comment: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/02/29/top-10-ways-to-embed-video-into-a-web-page/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three sites provide an "Embed this video" (or similar) link near every video they allow to be shared. Use that.

Bypassing their player would be a violation of their terms (as you would be effectively sucking up the bandwidth they pay for without applying their branding / advertising to the video).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link that discusses all the above videos websites you mentioned.

http://www.onextrapixel.com/2012/02/29/top-10-ways-to-embed-video-into-a-web-page/

Comment: [How should helpful answers that are just links be handled?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116301/how-should-helpful-answers-that-are-just-links-be-handled)